# IntelliSense doesn't work in large XAML file

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intellisense, xaml-designer

After updating Visual Studio IntelliSense stopped working in one XAML file where about 2220 lines of code. 
It works in other files and starts working when I delete part of the code. 
I tried to delete the .vs folder, delete and add this file and it didn't help

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, no, your answer didn't help me but I believe it will help someone else. This is very similar to the update bug, my problem was solved after downgrade to the 2017 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IntelliSense doesn't work in large XAML file

Please try these steps:

**Suggestion**

**1)** Close VS Instance, delete `bin` and `obj` folder and then restart your project.

**2)** Right-click on the XAML file in the **Solution Explorer** and then select `Open With`>`Source Code (Text) Editor` and set it as default.

**3)** Right click the XAML file>`Properties`>`Build Action`>change it to something else and back

**4)** Add a new xaml file under this specific project and check if its intellisense works or not.

**5)** If you use Resharper Extension, please disable it under `Extensions`-->`Manage Extensions` and then restart your VS.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled resharper and xaml auto complete does not working anymore. What I have tried:

1. stackoverflow.com answer, not working
2. Repare by vs installer, not working
3. Uninstall completely and reinstall, not working

At last, I resetted vs setting(Tool => Import and export settings), the xaml auto complete function works again.

Note: although the auto list member option is gray out and unchecked (I use 17.6.2 and 17.1 preview 1), but after reset vs settings, xaml auto complete works well.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me "2) Right-click on the XAML file in the Solution Explorer and then select Open With>Source Code (Text) Editor and set it as default."

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue after upgrading to Visual Studio 2022 17.6. After wasting time trying to figure this silly problem out, I stumbled upon this thread. Suggestion #2 from Mr Qian worked for me. Thank you!
It appears that 17.6 simply defaults your default editor for XAML to their new XML editor.
Why Microsoft does these things boggles the mind.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).